# How to search nodes (documents) matching with a range of conditions in MarkLogic by XCC

Tags: marklogic

I am a newbie in MarkLogic, so please help me to find a solution.

My XML data are imported in to MarkLogic, and I want to find documents (nodes) with a specific range condition using XCC.
I run below search command, but get an error.
Please tell me what I was wrong and show me the solution.
Thank you.

```
cts:search(fn:doc(),
  cts:and-query(cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("RequestDatetime"), ">=", "20141102170000"), 
  cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("RequestDatetime"), "<=", "20141103170000"))
```

Error contents is

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected UnterminatedComment_, expecting Function30_ or Percent_
```

Hi wst and other

I tried to create element-range-index, but it seems not to be working.
My data contains many XML file with the format as below.
Now If I want to seach range for the Element of *RequestDatetime* , what I have to do?

Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
    <RequestDatetime>
        20141102174108
    </RequestDatetime>
    <RemoteHostName>
        xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
    </RemoteHostName>
    <OrgRequest>
       GET http://xxxx/ HTTP/1.1
    </OrgRequest>
    <Protocol>
        xxxx
    </Protocol>
    <WebServer>
        xxxxxxxxx
    </WebServer>
    <Request>
        xxxxxxxxxxx
    </Request>
    <StatusCode>
    xxxxxxx
    </StatusCode>
    <BytesSent>
        Xxxxxxxxxx
    </BytesSent>
    <UserAgent>
    </UserAgent>
    <RemoteLogName>
    </RemoteLogName>
    <Cookie>
    </Cookie>
    <Referer>
    </Referer>
    <UserName>
    </UserName>
</Request>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cts:queries` passed to `cts:and-query` are a sequence, so they need to be enclosed in parens (unlike `fn:concat()`):

```
cts:search(fn:doc(),
  cts:and-query((
    cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("RequestDatetime"), ">=", "20141102170000"), 
    cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("RequestDatetime"), "<=", "20141103170000")
  ))
)
```

Comment: Thanks wst. 
I followed you answer but getting another error. 

[1.0-ml] XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND: cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:and-query((cts:element-range-query(fn:QName("", "RequestDatetime"), ">=", "20141102170000", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/"), 1), cts:element-range-query(fn:QName("", "RequestDatetime"), "<=", "20141103170000", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/"), 1)), ())) -- No string element range index for fn:QName("", "RequestDatetime") http://marklogic.com/collation/

Comment: @manhtc To use `cts:element-range-query` you need to have a range index configured in your database settings (see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index). FYI, `xs:unsignedLong` might be a good type for your range index.

Comment: I see. I will try and check the result again.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I have updated the question contents, please see if you have time. Thank you.

Comment: @manhtc That shouldn't affect the answer. If you are still having problems, please accept this answer and post a new question detailing the new problem, including any errors you receive.